# How to set the default page of a folder to open when the user enters the folder URL?

Tags: java, jsf

If i have a page in the path, let's say, `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/admin/login.xhtml`, how to set this login.xhtml as the default page to this folder, when the user types `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/admin/` ?
And i dont want this page to be in welcome file list, i want it to be the default page ONLY for this folder.

----- EDIT -----

As @joe776 suggested, i tried to put an index.jsp inside my `admin` folder, with a `<jsp:forward page="login.xhtml" />` on it, and it works, but only on the first time! If the user types again `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/admin/`, it shows an error `/admin/paginas/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource`, where `paginas` is a folder inside the `admin` folder. If the user quits the browser, open it again and types the same URL it works, but again, only for the first time. Is tomcat getting crazy or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jpr said, i used a Filter to redirect to the login page, only strange thing is that i needed to get the url and do the forward again when the user enters the "/admin" folder, because it was redirecting to the wrong page, don't know why.
But my code now looks like this:

@WebFilter({"/admin/paginas/*"})

```
public class LoginFilter implements Serializable, Filter{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
//      HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        HttpSession httpSession=req.getSession(true);
        Object administradorLogado=httpSession.getAttribute("administrador");
        System.out.println("Entrando no loginFileter!");

        if (administradorLogado == null) {
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/admin/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }else{
            String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
            System.out.println("URL que peguei no filter admin: "+url);
            if(url.endsWith("admin/")){
                RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/admin/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
                requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }else{
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to put an `index.jsp` in that folder and let it redirect to your `login.xhtml`. Another way is to add `login.xhtml` as welcome page.

The Tomcat docs give an example for both possibilities: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F

Answer (score 0):

You can add a security constraint to your web.xml. A sample as follows

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected</web-resource-name>
        <description>Protected Page</description>
        <url-pattern>/admin/ *</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name/>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

So every time you try to access anything in admin folder, it will direct you to login page.

### Edit

to just redirect to /admin/login.xhtml you can use a filter. Here is a sample code of a jsf filter's doFilter method you can modify for your purpose.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    RequestDispatcher rd;
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
    if (requestURI.equalsIgnoreCase("/index.xhtml")) {           
            rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/admin/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
            rd.forward(request, response);
    }else{
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

}

Comment: But i still want my users to access the pages within the Admin folder... How does it work then with this security constraint?

Comment: if you want the users to access the dmin folder without logging in, then I guess the only thing you want is to redirect to /admin/login.xhtml? For that you can use a filter. Inside the doFilter method, check if the request is for your welcomepage and then forward the request to the /admin/login.xhtml. I modify my original answer with the sample code of the doFilter method you can change for your purpose.